# Rows not working properly: only first row gets updated while trying to Edit a custom table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, js

I have a custom table whose contents are fetched from a JSON data.
When I click on edit button , all rows become editable but I'm only able to edit and save the first row correctly.
When I try to edit the second or third row , then also only the first row gets updated with the input I provided in the 2nd or 3rd rows.
Stuck here and don't understand why this is happening!!

My JSON data:

```json
[{"vendorName":"Vendor1","vCity":"Toronto","vCompany":"google"}
,{"vendorName":"Vendor2","vCity":"Tokyo","vCompany":"Yahoo"}]
```

Now i am displaying the data in my html as below

```html
<!--Table Body-->
          <tbody>
            <template for:each={jsonData} for:item="item" for:index="index">
              <tr data-index={index} key={item.id} class="slds-hint-parent">

                <td class="slds-size_1-of-6">
                  <div>
                    <template if:false={item.isChanged}>{item.vendorName}</template>
                    <template if:true={item.isChanged}>
                      <lightning-input key={item.id} data-id={item.id} data-index={index} name="vendorName" 
                                            value={item.vendorName} variant="label-hidden" 
                                            onchange={handleValueChange}></lightning-input>
                    </template>
                  </div>
                </td>
                    
<!-- there are couple more lightning input here which are similar to above-->
<!-- edit -->
                  <td class="slds-size_1-of-6" data-index={index} data-id={item.id}>
                  <div class ="slds-col">
                      <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:edit" variant = "bare" 
                                      data-index={index} size="xx-small"
                                      alternative-text="edit" onclick={handleEditClick}></lightning-button-icon>                  
                  </div>                  
                </td>                  
                </td>
              </tr>
```

My JS:

```js
@track jsonData = [];
@track isChanged = false;

    handleEditClick(e){
        this.isChanged = true;
    }


handleValueChange(event){
        let element = this.jsonData.find(ele =>ele.Id === event.target.dataset.id);
        element[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        this.jsonData = [...this.jsonData];
        console.log('value',JSON.stringify(this.jsonData));

    }

handleSave(){
        let dataList = this.jsonData;
        dataList.forEach((element, index) => {
            if(element.name === ''){
                dataList.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
        console.log('dataList',JSON.stringify(this.dataList));
        this.jsonData = dataList;
        updateVendorInfo({recJson : JSON.stringify(this.dataList)})
        .then(() => {
            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title : 'Success',
                    message : `Records saved !`,
                    variant : 'success',
                }),
            );
            this.isChanged = false;
            this.error = undefined;
            return refreshApex(this.jsonData);
            
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
            console.log("Error in Save call back:", this.error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
            }, 3000);
        });
}
```

Any insight guys ???

Answer (score 0):

Remember, when you have a table, you have a multidimensional set of data (rows and columns). Therefore, a proper solution will include two accesses, such as `this.tableData[row][column]`. In addition, `tableFields` makes no sense here, just edit the `jsonData` directly.

```
handleValueChange(event){
    const row = this.jsonData.find(record => record.Id === event.target.dataset.id);
    row[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that JavaScript is case sensitive. `event.target.Name` is not the same as `event.target.name`. Also, make sure that `lightning-input` element's `name` matches the field's name: `name="vendorName"`.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thank you for your inputs. I have adjusted my code keeping in mind what you suggested. But , now, when I click on save , first my table gets updated ,but , when i refresh my page the table again shows the old data!!!

Comment: @Azad refreshApex(this.jsonData) is incorrect; this data doesn't contain the original request data. You need to refresh the wired property or call your Apex again. You didn't include this in your code, so I can't tell you exactly what you need to fix.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I am facing a different problem. When I edit the cell in 2nd row , still only my first row is getting updated and the second row remains the same. I am using for:each in my html, but, I don't know why this is happening! Any insights?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Still stuck with the row error. Only able to edit or save the first row in my table!!

Comment: @Azad If I had to guess, I'd say that `Id` is null, so you're finding the first row. Are you sure every row has an Id? Maybe you could use the index of the row instead, if this is new data?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my jsonData was missing a property to identify the rows. So, after fetching the jsonData, I added a id in my js code, which resulted in below:

Modified jsonData:

```json
[{"id":0,"vendorName":"Vendor1","vCity":"Toronto","vCompany":"google"}
,{"id":1,"vendorName":"Vendor2","vCity":"Tokyo","vCompany":"Yahoo"}]
```

and I made the following changes to my handleValueChange method as @sfdcfox had suggested to provide two sets of accesses which resulted in below:

```js
handleValueChange(){
      let var1 = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
      let var2 = event.target.name;
      this.jsonData[var1] [var2] = event.target.value;
}
```

and in my handleSave method i added

```js
var dataList = [...this.jsonData];
```

before proceeding to iterate over dataList and it worked!!
If anyone else finds this helpful, kindly upvote it so that it may help others.